# c# Connecting to a local MDF DB File

Tags: c#, database, connection, mdf

On my development computer I have MS SQL Server/Visual Studio 2005. My program can correctly connect to my local DB and use it. However my other computer (non-dev) does not have MS SQL Server/Visual Studio 2005 and does not connect to the DB. It spits out the following:

"An error has occurrred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. ..." (Error: 26).

Does this mean I have to install SQL Server 2005 on my non-dev computers? Is there any other way?

My connection string is:

"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"" 
            + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() 
            + "\DB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection string is telling the Sql Server Native Client ADO.NET Provider to attempt to connect to a Sql Server instance named **SQLEXPRESS** that will manage the database stored in a file **DB.mdf**.  Since your client computer does not have Sql Server Express installed, it's not going to find a database to connect to.

You will need to:

- Install Sql Server on the client computer and deploy your database there.
- Switch to Sql Server Compact Edition (SqlCE - embedded database) and re-architect your application to use the portable database file (with SqlCE) instead.
- Ditch using a robust database engine and switch entirely to ADO.NET DataSets, saving/loading the contents of the DataSet to an Xml file (via *WriteXml()* and *ReadXml()*).  If the amount of data you are processing is fairly limited in size, DataSets are a good approach to maintaining integrity (via a strongly typed and well-defined schema) and portability.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run it on that other pc/server you also need to have SQL Server (need to attach your .mdf to it) or SQL Server Express installed.

Another trick would be to change your connection string so that it points out to another pc/server where your database runs on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need MS-SQL (Express) available on your target computers. Either a local install or a connection to a server.

It is not that difficult to include SQl Express in a Setup.exe (see PreRequisites).

An alternative is to use SQL-CE or Sqlite or (even) MS-Access. They are 'embedded' database engines so that you only need to distribute DLLs.

Comment: I converted to SQLCE... now Visual Studio adds a System.Data.SqlServeCe.dll to the output path. Removing this dll obvious creates an exception. But when I copy the output with the DLL file to the non-dev computer, it spits out the same error as running it without a DLL. Anyone know why this would happeN?

Comment: The SqlServerCe dll is normally installed in the GAC. Using it separately may not be recommended, but: copy the DLL to your Source folder (not \bin\) add a reference to _that_ dll and make sure CopyLocal is set. It may depend on other DLLs though, you need a tight(er) match on Fx version.